# Is this use of CompareToBuilder considered inefficient?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

During peer reviews, a developer seemed horrified at the thought of implementing the compareToBuilder solution I chose to sort by 3 attributes.  He is under the impression that the compareTo method in my class would create an inordinate number of comparators, for each individual comparison, and the app would take a huge hit on performance.  He suggested I utilize BeanComparator & ComparatorUtils to chain comparators.

This is my class:

```
public class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

@Override
public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
    return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(o1.getJobTitle(), o2.getJobTitle())
            .append(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge())
            .append(o1.getSalary(), o2.getSalary()).toComparison();
}
```

This is my implementation:

```
Collections.sort(outputRecordList, Comparator.nullsLast(new EmployeeComparator()));
```

However, I don't actually know if this is true.  I cannot find anything that would indicate that this would be a significant performance hit over using a chained comparator.  I dug through the apache documentation and it appears that this is a standard implementation of the class (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html).  The only concern I have is that by adding the "Comparator.nullsLast", I have created a monster.

I found the CompareToBulder implementation on this site here:

http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example

Any help either explaining why this is bad practice or explain what exactly CompareToBuilder is doing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Understandable.  I will post it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code reviews: *home of the micro optimisation*. I don't see how he could predict that it will be "a huge hit on performance" based on such limited information.

Was there a non-functional requirement for your code to be faster than X? If there wasn't, feel free to ignore his comment. Your code is readable, reusable, and maintainable. It doesn't matter if it does 1 or 2 lightning-fast comparisons more than is strictly necessary. Unless you're comparing these things in the millions at a time, it will make literally no practical difference. Any time spent considering it is just time wasted.

---

The correct approach to optimising any code is:

1. measure whether there is a legitimate problem
2. decide what the level of acceptable performance is
3. optimise the code and re-measure until it is, at least, acceptable

Repeat as necessary

Answer (score 4):

The CompareToBuilder seems reasonably efficient for your usage (from looking at its source code). When compared against a hard-coded comparison, it involves one additional instance creation (containing only one int field) plus the append() calls (can probably be inlined by the HotSpot compiler). And it has to go through all tail comparisons even if the first comparison already decided the result.

Implement it that way and then do a profiling of the system. If EmployeeComparator takes significant time, think again: but I guess a faster compareTo() implementation won't help very much, then.

Comment: I agree but you're giving his colleague's opinion too much weight when you say to profile it. How is he supposed to decide what counts as "significant time", anyway? I'd bet good money there are significantly worse performance bottlenecks in their application than simply sorting a list.

Comment: When I said "do a profiling of the system" I meant an overall profiling, not a specific one focusing on the Comparator. I'd always recommend to spend an hour or two on running a software system under profiling conditions and having a look at the results. We spend so much time on other quality aspects that a short preemptive efficiency analysis should be OK as well. And it's not only about meeting requirements but also resposibility for wasting electric energy in our CPUs,

Comment: I agree in theory but you're inventing requirements out of thin air. From a business perspective, that's nothing but a waste of time.

Comment: @Michael: sorry, I'm German, and we (sometimes) strive for perfection, not just good-enough-quality ;-)